# Server doesn't enable my spigot plugin. (It doesn't even try)

Tags: java, bukkit

**I'm basically making a spigot plugin, for practice.**

The server doesn't enable the server, no error in the console. It also no "INFO" for enabling the plugin.

This is my main class

```java
package me.FarrosGaming.SpawnPillager;

import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;

import me.FarrosGaming.SpawnPillager.commands.PillagerCommand;

public class Main extends JavaPlugin {
    @Override
    public void onEnable() {
        new PillagerCommand(this);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onDisable() {
        
    }
}
```

This is my command class

```java
package me.FarrosGaming.SpawnPillager.commands;

import org.bukkit.Location;
import org.bukkit.World;
import org.bukkit.command.Command;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandExecutor;
import org.bukkit.command.CommandSender;
import org.bukkit.entity.EntityType;
import org.bukkit.entity.Player;

import me.FarrosGaming.SpawnPillager.Main;

public class PillagerCommand implements CommandExecutor {
    private Main plugin;
    
    public PillagerCommand(Main plugin) {
        this.plugin = plugin;
        plugin.getCommand("chase").setExecutor(this);
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command command, String label, String[] args) {
        
        if (!(sender instanceof Player)) {
            sender.sendMessage("Only players who can send this command.");
            return true;
        }
        
        Player player = (Player) sender;
        
        if (player.hasPermission("hello.use")) {
            Location location = player.getLocation();
            World world = player.getWorld();
            
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                world.spawnEntity(location, EntityType.CREEPER);
            }
            
            return true;
        } else {
            player.sendMessage("You do not have a permission to use this command");
        }
        
        return false;
    }
    
}
```

this is my plugin.yml file

```yaml
name: SpawnPillager
version: 1.0
author: FarrosGaming
description: blabla
main: me.FarrosGaming.SpawnPillager.Main

commands:
  chase:
    description: Spawn pillager in your location
    usage: /chase
```

Literally, there are no spaces in the plugin.yml
I'm using the newest version of spigot.

Comment: Are you sure the plugin is in your `plugins` directory and you've restarted the server after putting the jar in that directory? Mainly a sanity check as nothing else immediately looks wrong with your code/plugin.yml

Comment: @Lucan yes, I'm putting my jar file into plugins folder, and I have restarted the server, nothing happened.

Comment: Did you make sure to export the .jar correctly?

Answer (score 0):

make sure you are dropping your plugin's Jar in the right spot, i mean the right server's plugins folder, if you multiple and then reload/ restart your server,
I m telling this coz, me myself, have done this mistake too..